# Error in Spring Boot app - Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'topology'] to topologyEndpoint

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

When I try to start my Spring Boot Service I get the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmxMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/jmx/JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'topology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.quest.orbital.group.service.Application.main(Application.java:41)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'topology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'topology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.assertNoDuplicateOperations(EndpointDiscoverer.java:231)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.convertToEndpoint(EndpointDiscoverer.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.convertToEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.jmxMBeanExporter(JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I use Spring Boot, WebFlux.
I was able to start my service a couple of days ago but today - with this error. My service compiles without any problems. I don't have any duplicated endpoints in my cotrollers. I use OPENAPI to generate controllers.

Do you have any idea? What informations should I add to this post? I don't have any idea what's the problem:(

I cleaned the Gradle caches, removed everything and cloned the repo one more time. It seems that it must be a problem on my laptop? The only thing I changed recently was starting Kubernetes on Docker Desktop (win10 pro) but other services start without problems...

Answer (score 23):

The answer is Intellij in my case - after recent update I had to uncheck **Enable JMX agent** in Project Configurations

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error started showing up in my project after upgrading to Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR4.

Downgrading to Hoxton.SR3 it went back to normal.

Comment: Yes I think this is related too to Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR4. Same behavior on my side